# Why does the implementation of a method from a interface cast parameters to Object(or extends YourObject)?

Tags: java, generics, types, interface, casting

I have a interface

```
public interface GenericRepository<T extends GenericObject> {
    String add(T t);
}
```

I tried to implement it as expected

```
public class GenericMongoRepository<T extends GenericObject> 
implements GenericRepository{
@Override
public String add(T  t) {
  return null;
}
```

This does not work. The interface expects an implementation like this.

```
public class GenericMongoRepository<T extends GenericObject> 
implements GenericRepository{
@Override
public String add(GenericObject  genericObject) {
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement an interface you also need to pass in the T, which is taken from the implementation(replaced with the type).

Solution:

```
public class GenericMongoRepository<T extends GenericObject> 
implements GenericRepository<T>{
@Override
public String add(T genericObject) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Parameter in method can be T now, +1

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the implementation of a method from a interface cast parameters to Object(or extends YourObject)?

It doesn't.

> The interface expects an implementation like this.

```
public class GenericMongoRepository<T extends GenericObject> 
implements GenericRepository
@Override
public String add(T  t) {
  return null;
}
```

No it doesn't. It expects this:

```
public class GenericMongoRepository<T extends GenericObject> 
implements GenericRepository<T>
@Override
public String add(T  t) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to point out that if you forget the <T> the expected implementation changes, since no T type is passed in. I guess it can be a confusing explanation.